# MySQL collecting results regardless of spaces

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small application which I have collecting user input and returning a set of results based on the input. The input is a postcode so for example, pl4 7by. Which has a space between it. This is the format of which the data is stored in. I wish to have applicable postcodes returned from the search even if a user inputs without the space between or multiple spaces.

This is currently what I have.

```
<?php
$input = $_GET["input"] . "%";
try{
    $handler = new PDO();
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $handler -> prepare("
    SELECT * FROM `LSOA_postcodes` WHERE postcode LIKE :input LIMIT 20
");
$stmt -> execute([
    ":input" => $input
]);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Postcode</th><th>LSOA Code</th><th>LSOA Name</th></tr>";

while($row = $stmt -> fetchObject()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>", $row -> postcode, "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $row -> code, "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $row -> name, "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is functional and returns the results regardless of case. I could store the data with no spaces, but I wish to have the correct format display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Just had a sudden thought and came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM `LSOA_postcodes` WHERE REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(:input,' ', '') LIMIT 20
```

This works as planned from first sight. Is there any problems that I cannot see with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could trim the spaces on both sides of the `=` sign:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `LSOA_postcodes` 
WHERE  REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(:input, ' ', '') 
LIMIT  20
```

Notes:

1. You'll use any benefit on an index on `postcode`, if you had one.
2. <strike>I stayed with the `like` operator like OP suggested, although since there are no wild cards here, a simple `=` should do the trick</strike> - Did not notice the use of `%` online 2, as per comments below.

Comment: I used LIKE as I believe that makes it case insensitive. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Darryl no, this is not the case. Case (in)sensitivity is controlled by [the string's collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html), which effects both `like` and `=`.

Comment: Thank you. That is good to know. I also remember another reason I used LIKE, this is because I used the wildcard on line 2, to allow users to input the start of a postcode.

Comment: @Darryl completely missing line 2... My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of LSOA_postcodes, you may encounter performance problems using REPLACE as in the above 2 answers because it is unlikely to use index scans.

I would check the $input to see if it contains a space and add one if its length is > 3 - all in php then let the SQL do the search as in the original question.

Comment: The table is going to be roughly 200,000 rows long.

Comment: Is there an index on postcode?  If so, you **will** want to take advantage of it.  If you control the database the application is accessing and it doesn't have an index, consider adding one.